# Data not updating in Firebase and Ionic

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Ionic / Firebase and I try to update fields via a form. Everything works, no error, all console log show up what needed but the data are not being updated in the database.

Here is my controller :

```
 var database = firebase.database();
  var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  var nameInput = document.querySelector('#name');
  var descriptionInput = document.querySelector('#description');
  var saveButton = document.querySelector('#save');

  saveButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var name = nameInput.value;
    var description = descriptionInput.value;

    function writeUserData(name, description) {
      firebase.database().ref('accounts/' + userId).set({
        name: name,
        description: description,
      });
    }
    $state.go("tab.account");
  });
```

Any idea ? Or maybe a better method to simply update firebase's database via a form when the user is logged in ?

Comment: does this `writeUserData` function really been executed? seems you only declared it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you didn't really don't know the real significance/uses of function yet about when to use it

Well it's because you wrap it inside `writeUserData` and which is you didn't event execute/call this function

Also function `writeUserData` isn't necessary in this situation

so remove function it

```
var database = firebase.database();
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
var nameInput = document.querySelector('#name');
var descriptionInput = document.querySelector('#description');
var saveButton = document.querySelector('#save');

receiveNewData();

function receiveNewData() {
    // check if there's new data added
    firebase.database().ref('accounts/' + userId).on('child_added', function(msg) {
        var data = msg.val();
        // your new data
        console.log(data);
        $state.go("tab.account");
    });
}

saveButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var name = nameInput.value;
    var description = descriptionInput.value;

    firebase.database().ref('accounts/' + userId).set({
        name: name,
        description: description,
    });
});
```

You just transfer `$state.go("tab.account");` to `receiveNewData`

**Edited**

To be able to catch the changes just call add `child_added` event listener inside 'accounts/' + userId

```
function receiveNewData() {
    firebase.database().ref('accounts/' + userId).on('child_added', function(msg) {
        var data = msg.val();
        // your new data
        console.log(data);
        $state.go("tab.account");
    });
}
```

Comment: Waow ! Thank you ! I can't believe it ! Now when it goes to the "tab.account", the changes are not showing, I have to log out and loggin again to see it. Any idea ?

Comment: Thank you for this, however it doesn't seem to work. A typo or something ? I mean it saves etc but it doesn't show up by going to the other page.

Comment: I have this error : `TypeError: firebase.database(...).ref.child is not a function` so we get rid of the action to go back to "tab.account" ? Thanks again for your time you have no idea how frustrated I got with that...

Comment: This time no error but still it doesn't change the data. Now that I see that, if I click on other tabs and come back on the tab.account I still don't see it changing (even if it has been changed in the database). Maybe I need something to refresh the data when visiting the page itself ?

Comment: I forgot to include the `$state.go("tab.account");` hehehe inside `child_added` event listener

Comment: Well still the same, I won't bother you more, you already did a LOT ! Thank you for your time !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135734/discussion-between-frenchynyc-and-beginner).